# how to make another level in python platform game

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make it so when you walk off the screen to the right it will enter level 2, but I have no clue on how to do this.

I also have a platform glitch but no one knows how to answer it on the post I made so I guess I'll just leave it because I can't fix it.

This is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

bg = pygame.image.load('C:\Python34/2d/bg.png')
player1 = pygame.image.load('C:\Python34/2d/player.png')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("use arows")

movex = 0

class player:

    def __init__(self ,x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 112
        self.height = 112
        self.velocity = 0
        self.falling = False
        self.onGround = False

    def jump(self):
        if(self.onGround == False):
            return

        self.velocity = 8
        self.onGround = False

    def detectCollisions(self,x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2):
        if (x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2):
            return True
        elif (x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2):
            return True
        elif (x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2):
            return True
        elif (x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2):
            return True    
        else:
            return False

    def update(self, gravity, blockList):
        if (self.velocity < 0):
            self.falling = True

        collision = False
        blockX,blockY =  0,0
        for block in blockList:

            collision = self.detectCollisions(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height )
            if collision == True:
                blockx = block.x
                blocky = block.y
                break

        if(collision == True):
            if self.falling == True:
                self.falling = False
                self.onGround = True
                self.velocity = 0
                self.y = blocky - self.height

        if (self.onGround == False):
            self.velocity += gravity
        self.y -= self.velocity

    def render(self,screen):
        screen.blit(player1,(self.x,self.y))

class Block:
    def __init__ (self, x, y):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.width = 32
       self.height = 32

    def render(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(9,203,27),(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

gravity = -0.5

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (50,60,200)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = player(0,0)

# 25 colums and 19 rows
level1 = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]

blockList = []

for y in range (0,len(level1)):
    for x in range (0,len(level1[y])):
        if (level1[y][x] == 1):
            blockList.append(Block(x*32, y*32))

gameloop = True

while gameloop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameloop = False

        if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                movex = 5
            elif(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                movex = -5
            elif (event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                player.jump()

        if(event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                movex = 0
            elif(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                movex = 0

    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))

    for block in blockList:
        block.render(screen)
    player.x += movex

    player.update(gravity, blockList)
    player.render(screen)
    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You are probably going to have to improve the design and structuring of your code in order to do this. Specifically you will need to store the layout for each level in some sort of a variable. Making a specific data structure to store each level would be a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I store my levels in text files, but the way you have it set up will work. Just test if the player is past the right edge of the map, (eg:`if playerX > 1200`) then reload the map as the second map, (basically, just have an active map that copies other maps onto it for active use) Then set the playerX to 0 or something.

For my game, I have all of my maps stored as text files with them named World,X,Y.
I load them with `file = open(''+(str(World))+','+(str(X))+','+(str(Y))+'','r')` (I don't care what people think of how I do my strings. :P) Then it it mostly automated.